# Is there a way to force a resolution on Android when using Monogame?

Tags: c#, xna, android, monogame, xamarin

I think I looked everywhere but I couldn't find a way.
My phone has a native resolution of 1920x1080 and I would like to run my game at 1280x720.

I tried by changing PreferredBackBufferWidth and PreferredBackBufferHeight but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is this possible?

Comment: When are you setting PreferredBackBufferWidth/Height? You should call it in the same function where you create the GraphicsDeviceManager

Comment: Yes. I do all that in the constructor of the Game class.

Comment: Android won't adapt its internal resolution. It will just scale the buffer from 1280x720 to 1920x1080. You sure it isn't already happening?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are calling ApplyChanges() in the GraphicsDevice object after you set the width & height.

Also, try setting the PrefferedBackBufferWidth & Height in the Initialize().

I've ran into issues when trying to set it within the constructor of the Game class.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that, too. Still no luck. Even doing this in an empty project still doesn't work.

Comment: Is graphics.Fullscreen set to true?

Comment: Yes, I tried all the combinations.

Comment: So wait. When you run the game on the android device, what happens?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the mobile device ***cannot*** run in anything other than the native resolution.

Fear not, you can use [resolution independance](http://blog.roboblob.com/2013/07/27/solving-resolution-independent-rendering-and-2d-camera-using-monogame/comment-page-1/) for this. 
The `spriteBatch.Begin()` method has a transformation matrix parameter.
You can use it to scale everything- so you can work in the resolution you like.
The resolution you want the game to be is the *virtual resolution*.

```
Matrix scaleMatrix=Matrix.CreateScale(
                        nativewidth/virtualwidth,
                        nativeheight/virtualheight,
                        1f);
```

Now pass that value to the `spritebatch.Begin()`:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(transformMatrix: scaleMatrix);
```

Your sprites will now be transformed to match the native resolution- but it will look like you had the virtual resolution.

Note that for 3D your projection matrix would be calculated for the intended viewport anyway.